# Secured Login, do not allow user to navigate using URL

Tags: java, jsp

I am in the process of creating a dynamic webpage and have a Login page - Login.jsp which on successful authentication will redirect to another page, say Page1.jsp.

But however, if I change the URL of the webpage to "...Projname/Page1.jsp" I can bypass the login page and access the Page1.jsp.

How do I stop this, appreciate your help on this please.

Comment: you need a filter for pages you want to check if user is logged in...
you could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961940/how-jsp-page-should-check-authentication

Comment: Create a session when user logins and store some data in session varaible. if a user tries to open the Page1.jsp and session varialbe has the ncessary data, then go ahead and send the page. otherwise send an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On successfull login in Login.jsp page you can set some `Session` variable so the same can be verified while loading the `Page1.jsp` to check whether it has valid username or not before loading the page

Try something like this in your `Page1.jsp` :

```
<%
//get UserName to verify 
String userName= (String) session.getAttribute("userName");
if(userName!=null)
{

//user is valid

}
else
{

//return here as user is invalid
response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp");

}


%>
<HTML>
<BODY>
Hello, <%= session.getAttribute("userName") %>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Note: you should make the `userName` Session variable to null when user logout from his page / close the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work a lot in JSP but in PHP I would redirect you to login page if you are not logged in.

I believe it is done like this in JSP:

```
if (!checkIfLoggedIn()) {
  response.sendRedirect(urlToLoginPage);
}
```

More info on:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_page_redirect.htm

Comment: You can simply use `response.sendRedirect(url)`.